# Fetch wont work in getStaticProps for ISR but works for CSR

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch some data using the -

```
import { useBhagwadGitaQuote, useTime } from '../api/Endpoints';
...
...
(default export component code)
...
...
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { timeData } = await useTime();
  console.log(timeData);
  

  return {
    props: {
      timeData
    },
    revalidate: 86400,
  };
}
```

The useTime is defined as -

```
export const useTime = async () => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
  };

  const link = 'https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata';
  const raw = await fetch(link, options);
  const timeData = await raw.json();
  console.log(timeData);
  return { timeData, isLoading: !timeData };
};
```

When I run it with `yarn run dev` it does not works and throws this error -

[image]

However, it works fine with Client Side Rendering, When I call the Hook `useTime`, inside the functional component, at the client's end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384453/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usestate-in-next-js)

Comment: @yousoumar No it doesn't. I'm not using any hooks inside getStaticProps. It's more of a function than a react hook. Also, A similar function or a "hook" works perfectly fine inside the getStaticProps. Not sure why the issue is happening with this particular API